# Trying to create a chrome extension which scrolls down the page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a chrome extension something like this

If i click on the extension icon page should start scrolling down, and keep scrolling until i click the icon again (toggle)

manifest.json is

```
{
    "name": "scrolldown",
    "description": "scroll down the page",
    "version": "0.1",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "background": {
       "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js is

```
var toggle=false;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    toggle = !toggle;
    if (toggle) {
        var time = setInterval(function() {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,
                {
                    code: 'window.scrollBy(0, 1000);'
                }
            );
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        clearInterval(time);
    }

});
```

This code is half correct i.e If i click on the icon page start scrolling down , but if i click on icon again page does not stop . It keep scorlling down ,

i think there is something wrong in background.js

please help

Comment: yikes, maybe if you cleaned up your code, you (or especially other people) would have more luck debugging...!

Comment: @Andrew Please edit my question if you have time

Comment: no problem -- there you go :) i apologize that i haven't much experience with chrome extensions so i'm not sure i can help further :(

Comment: @Andrew Thanks, now its looking better

Comment: are you able to clear the interval via the developer's console?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that i mean  how can i pass parameter to `clearInterval(param)` in console @Andrew

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: If you can't do `clearInterval(time)` from the console then the problem is probably that `time` is inaccessible or outside the scope. Try instead writing `var time;` right under the `var toggle` declaration, then remove the keyword `var` on your setInterval call. If that fixes your issue, I'll repost as an answer

Comment: @Andrew Huraahhhh!  It works, Thanks andrew , post it as an answer, And please explain reason behind it as well

Comment: i'm glad i could help you! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `time` is inaccessible from the global scope.

You should declare `var time` outside the function like so:

```
var toggle = false;
var time;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    toggle = !toggle;
    if (toggle) {
        time = setInterval(function() {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,
                {
                    code: 'window.scrollBy(0, 1000);'
                }
            );
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        clearInterval(time);
    }

});
```

This puts `time` into the global scope.

For more info on scopes check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) on StackOverflow, and read about [JavaScript closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) as well.

Comment: Andrew although i got the solution ,But even after reading those links i am still confused , i defined var time and accessing it within same function, So it should be accessible in `clearInterval(time)`

Comment: No worries. You're actually calling a new function every time you click the extension button, as the function is entirely defined within addListener; thus, it is not the same function every time. Does that make sense? I can edit the question for more clarity if you'd like.

Comment: @beginner Do you still need help?

Comment: I get it now ,  Thank you so much andrew ,

Comment: No problem!! Happy coding :)